# Restoring an accidentally deleted iMessage thread using my iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, backup

I have the full iMessage thread on my iPad, but accidentally deleted it off of my iPhone.

How can I transfer the full thread to my iPhone?

Comment: Just wondering, are both the iPhone and iPad signed in with the same Apple ID and iCloud, **and** with Handoff and Continuity enabled? I ask because I do know of one person who deleted a conversation on their iPad but not on their iPhone, and then later started a new conversation on their iPad and all of the previous messages reappeared, presumably because the messages were still on their iPhone and they had Handoff/Continuity enabled. I know that's the reverse of your situation, since you've deleted the conversation from your iPhone, but just something worth checking.